# How to fake a loading gif for a picture

Tags: javascript, html, image, loading, gif

I'm currently building a "live webcam" system for some pets so that they can be monitored from far away (overseas) and I want to have a loading gif that displays for a certain time and then shows a picture. I want the picture to be displayed on a delay for added authenticity. Its basically a joke to have a "loading gif" because the image size is so small, it loads right away. Here is my current code:

```
<div  class="entry" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
<img src="pictureloading.gif" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
<img src="mostrecentimage.jpeg" alt="camDown.gif" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
</div>
```

The problem with this is that the only picture ever seen is the "mostrecentimage.jpg" and I want to have the "picture loading" image display for about a second before the "mostrecentimage" is showed. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Use javascript setTimeout() funtion. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

**HTML**

```
<div class="entry" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
<img src="pictureloading.gif" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.entry").find("img").attr("src","mostrecentimage.jpeg");
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

doing it with javascript will be the easiest way. just search for loading spinner or loading images. there are several examples on the www. 
e.g. http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/

http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/